# How to Append multiple child xml on existing xml data in PL SQL

Tags: xml, plsql

I wan to append  multiple child xml on existing xml data.

here is my pl sql function code:

```
select SALPROFILE  into rs from SALARYPROFILE where EMPID = 'ID123';    
    with xmlTab(val) as (
    select xmlType(rs.getClobval())
    from dual
    )
    select APPENDCHILDXML( val,
                           'employee',
                           XMLType('<PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>BANK LOAN-7</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM><PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>12500</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>')                           
                         ) into APPENDX     
    from xmlTab;
```

But  `XMLType` inside `APPENDCHILDXML` is not accepting multiple tags string.However,if only give 1 tag string such as  `XMLType('<PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>BANK LOAN-7</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>')` then it gets accepted.Moreover, i saw that [Appendchildxml](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions012.htm#SQLRF06201) function is deprecated.So, how can i solve this in very simple way.Is there any better and simple alternatives.please let me know for any further information.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code above isn't working is that:

```
'<PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>BANK LOAN-7</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>12500</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>'
```

is not valid as it has no root element. The following for example would work as it has a root node ("PAYMENT_INFO"):

```
select SALPROFILE  into rs from SALARYPROFILE where EMPID = 'ID123';    
with xmlTab(val) as (
  select xmlType(rs.getClobval())
  from dual
)
select APPENDCHILDXML( val,
                       'employee',
                       XMLType('<PAYMENT_INFO><PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>BANK LOAN-7</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM><PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>12500</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT></PAYMENT_INFO>')                           
                     ) into APPENDX     
from xmlTab;
```

I'm not great with using the new XQUERY stuff but there is a lot of information available on how to use it, this looks like it might point you in the right direction: [Inserting a child node in an XMLTYPE column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824336/inserting-a-child-node-in-an-xmltype-column)